# htaccess - directories/files in subfolder accessible via parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this directory structure:

```
/public_html
    /main
        /directory1
        /directory2
        file.php
        /public
            /js
            file1.php
```

I want to block/hide all directories and files in main folder expect public and when i go to mysite/main/file1.php this should return me file in mysite/main/public/file1.php
Same with folder js mysite/main/public/js/ should be accessible via mysite/main/js/

I have .htaccess file in my main directory which contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But server return 500 Internal Error (The server encountered an internal error and could not complete your request.).

Same with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

But for example (test) when i change to this:

```
RewriteRule ^f(.+)$ public/f$1 [L]
```

I have access to file1.php via url mysite/main/file1.php

Why I cant match "any characters"?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are looping, try adding a condition first:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: With RewriteCond i have 500 Internal Error too when i go to mysite/main/file1.php however i still have access to this file via mysite/main/public/file1.php

Comment: Interesting is that if i add flag R=301 everything works ok but ofc i have "public/" in url :/